# Not getting Shipment id in getShipment () in vendor/magento/module-sales/Block/Order/Email/Shipment/Items.php

Tags: magento2, email, shipment

I am not getting Shipment data in `getShipment`() in below file while sending shipment tracking information email from admin

```
in vendor/magento/module-sales/Block/Order/Email/Shipment/Items.php
```

Any thoughts please ?

Comment: Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a custom theme? If so check your shipment tracking email template in your child or parent theme :

```
THEME\Magento_Sales\view\frontend\templates\email\shipment\track.phtml
```

There is an issue with deprecated code in older email templates.

Edit `track.phtml` and around line 28 replace

```
<?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getNumber()) ?>
```

with

```
<a href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getTrackingUrl()->getUrl($_item)) ?>" target="_blank"> <?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getNumber()) ?> </a>
```

After making this change clear the cache and test again.

You can find more info about this issue here : https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/25221